# Problema con arreglo dinámico bidimensional en C

Tags: c

Intento hacer un programa para una tarea, el punto es que el arreglo si se llega a crear, sin embargo al imprimir los valores se imprimen datos basura y no se por que, cabe mencionar que la columna 5 del arreglo dará datos flotantes (supongo que el arreglo deberé hacerlo para flotantes), pero ahora solo me interesa que funcione para enteros.
El código es el siguiente:

```
int main(){
int **A;
int filas, i, j;

printf("Ingrese el numero de alumnos\n");
scanf("%d",&filas);
A = (int **)malloc(filas*sizeof(int *));
for (i=0; i<filas; i++)
    A[i] = (int *)malloc(5*sizeof(int));

    if (A==NULL)
        {
        printf("\nERROR de reservado de la memoria\n");
        exit(1);
        }

   for (i=0; i<filas; i++)
    {
        for (j=0; j<5; j++);
        A[i][j]=0;
    }

    for(i=0; i<filas; i++)
    {
        printf("Ingrese la matricula\t");
        scanf("%d",&A[i][0]);
        printf("Ingrese la calificacion 1\t");
        scanf("%d",&A[i][1]);
        printf("Ingrese la calificacion 2\t");
        scanf("%d",&A[i][2]);
        printf("Ingrese la calificacion 3\t");
        scanf("%d",&A[i][3]);
        A[i][4] = (A[i][1] + A[i][2] + A[i][3])/3;
    }

    printf("Matricula\tCalificacion 1\t Calificacion 2\t Calificacion 3\t Promedio\n");
    for (i=0; i<filas; i++);
    {
        printf("%d\t\t %d\t\t %d\t\t %d\t\t %d\n", A[i][0], A[i][1], A[i][2], A[i][3], A[i][4]);
    }

    for (i=0; i<filas; i++)
    {
        free (A[i]);
        free(A);
    }

return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

El error radica aquí:

```
for (j=0; j<5; j++); 
  A[i][j]=0;
```

El bucle for tiene un punto y coma, esto quiere decir, que la sentencia `A[i][j] = 0` no se  ejecutará las 5 veces.
La solución es quitar ese punto y coma:

```
for (j=0; j<5; j++)
  A[i][j]=0;
```

Ahora, hay varias fallas en el programa.

1. Se debe liberar la memoria reservada si llega a ocurrir un fallo en la asignación de memoria (asignado con `malloc`).

```
A = (int **)malloc(filas*sizeof(int *));
if(A == NULL)
{
    printf("Error: No se pudo asignar memoria!");
    return 1;
}
for (i=0; i<filas; i++)
{
    A[i] = (int *)malloc(5*sizeof(int));
    if(A[i] == NULL)
    {
       for(int x = 0; x != i; ++x)
       {
           //Liberamos la memoria que hayamos reservado para las columnas
           free(A[i]);
       }
       //Liberamos la memoria que reservamos para las filas.
       free(A); 
       printf("Error: No se pudo reservar memoria!");
       return 1;
    }
}
```

2. Esta forma no es la correcta para liberar la memoria:

```
for (i=0; i<filas; i++)
    {
        free (A[i]);
        free(A);
    }
```

Puesto, estarías liberando el búfer de punteros (`free(A)`) en cada iteración, esto hará que el programa aborte, debido a que, se está liberando algo que ya fue liberado.
Lo correcto sería hacerlo de esta forma:

```
for (i=0; i<filas; i++)
   free (A[i]);
free(A);
```

De ese modo, se libera cada array dinámico por separado y después, se procede a liberar el arreglo de punteros.

Comment: Excelente respuesta, salvo por un detalle: el motivo por el que `malloc` devuelve `NULL` no es por una *fuga de memoria* si no por no haber memoria disponible.

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster Gracias por la corrección. Ya corregí esa parte.